# Creating a matrix in Python with a range of numbers

Tags: python, list, matrix

I would like to create a matrix with cells that increment by 10. For example, the output of a 3x3 matrix should be:

`[[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]]`

The code I currently have creates a 3x3 matrix filled with 0s:

```
print([[0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)])

output: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: `range` takes a start, stop, and step argument you could probably leverage that. You will probably need to do some math based on number of rows and number of columns in the lists of lists so you probably want to make those variables. Look at the pattern in your desired result and formulate the code tying to implement it - I don't see you have attempted anything to get increments of ten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on for size

```
print([[30*y + 10*x for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)])
```

What this does is swaps out the `0` you were using with `30*y + 10*x` which is exactly what you need to generate your array. For a more general solution that lets you scale to n by n matrices you can use

```
n = k
print([[10*k*y + 10*x for x in range(k)] for y in range(k)])
```

For different rows and columns you can use

```
rows = k
cols = j
print([[10*cols*y + 10*x for x in range(cols)] for y in range(rows)])
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is not very compact but it gets the job done:

```
matrix = []
bar = []
foo = 10
  for i in range(3):
    for i in range(3):
  bar.append(foo)
  foo = foo + 10
matrix.append(bar)
bar = []
print(matrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` package is quite flexible for things you want:

```
import numpy as np
m = np.arange(10, 100, 10) #array [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
m = m.reshape(3,3) # array [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]]
print(m.tolist()) # array converted to list if you need
```

#### Output:

```
[[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(range(10,100,10)).reshape(3,3)
print(x)

[[10 20 30]
 [40 50 60]
 [70 80 90]]
```